# How to connect to containers in minikube?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes-helm, minikube

I'm learning by myself Helm trying to deploy 2 containers inside the same pod: one contains a postgres DB and the other contains pgadmin. I made the chart with a persistent-volume and an ingress. Now my problem is the access to containers, I can't reach my pgadmin through browser.
I don't understand why, reading documentation and youtube it seems that i wrote the chart correctly.

This is my values.yaml:

```
replicaCount: 1

image:
  postgresRepository: postgres
  postgresTag: "12.17-bullseye"
  pgadminRepository: dpage/pgadmin4
  pgadminTag: "8.2"
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

fullnameOverride: "helm-service"

postgresql:
  username: admin
  password: admin
  database: postgresDB
  port: 5432

pgadmin:
  email: admin@admin.com
  password: admin
  port: 5433

imagePullSecrets: [ ]

serviceAccount:
  create: false
  automount: false

podAnnotations: { }
podLabels:
  app: helm-postgres-helm-db-example

podSecurityContext: { }

securityContext: { }

postgresService:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 5432
  
pgadminService:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 8090

ingress:
  enabled: true
  className: "nginx"
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  hosts:
    - host: postgres.local
      paths:
        - path: /
          pathType: ImplementationSpecific
  tls: [ ]

resources: 
  limits:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 128Mi
  requests:
    cpu: 100m
    memory: 128Mi

autoscaling:
  enabled: false

persistentVolume:
  enabled: true
  name: postgres-data
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity: 100M
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
  claimName: postgres-data

persistentVolumeClaim:
  enabled: true
  name: postgres-data
  storageClassName: manual
  storage: 100M


volumes: 
  - name: postgres-data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: postgres-data

volumeMounts: 
  - name: postgres-data
    mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data

nodeSelector: { }

tolerations: [ ]

affinity: { }
```

Feel free to insult me if it's wrong ( ;) ).
Here's the rest of my chart:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: postgres-data
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 100M
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100M
  storageClassName: manual
  volumeName: postgres-data
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helm-db-example.fullname" . }}
spec:

  type: {{ .Values.pgadminService.type }}
  selector:
    app: {{ include "helm-db-example.fullname" . }}
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: {{ .Values.pgadminService.port }}
```

Here above there's the persistent volume,the persistent-volume-claim and my service.yaml.

This is my depoloyment.yaml.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "helm-db-example.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    {{- include "helm-db-example.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
spec:
  {{- if not .Values.autoscaling.enabled }}
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  {{- end }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      {{- include "helm-db-example.selectorLabels" . | nindent 6 }}
  template:
    metadata:
      {{- with .Values.podAnnotations }}
      annotations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      labels:
        {{- include "helm-db-example.labels" . | nindent 8 }}
        {{- with .Values.podLabels }}
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
        {{- end }}
    spec:
      {{- with .Values.imagePullSecrets }}
      imagePullSecrets:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ include "helm-db-example.serviceAccountName" . }}
      securityContext:
        {{- toYaml .Values.podSecurityContext | nindent 8 }}
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: "{{ .Values.image.postgresRepository }}:{{ .Values.image.postgresTag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: "{{ .Values.postgresql.username }}"
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              value: "{{ .Values.postgresql.password }}"
            - name: POSTGRES_DB
              value: "{{ .Values.postgresql.database }}"
          ports:
            - name: postgresql
              containerPort: {{ .Values.postgresService.port }}
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-data
              mountPath: {{ .Values.persistentVolume.hostPath }}
        - name: pgadmin
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 12 }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.pgadminRepository }}:{{ .Values.image.pgadminTag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          env:
            - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL
              value: "{{ .Values.pgadmin.email }}"
            - name: PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD
              value: "{{ .Values.pgadmin.password }}"
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: {{ .Values.pgadmin.port }}
              protocol: TCP
          resources:
            {{- toYaml .Values.resources | nindent 12 }}
          {{- with .Values.volumeMounts }}
          volumeMounts:
            {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
          {{- end }}
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: {{ .Values.persistentVolume.claimName }}
      {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
        {{- toYaml . | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
```

And that's my ingress.yaml.

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "helm-db-example.fullname" . -}}
{{- $svcPort := .Values.pgadmin.port -}}
{{- if and .Values.ingress.className (not (semverCompare ">=1.18-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion)) }}
  {{- if not (hasKey .Values.ingress.annotations "kubernetes.io/ingress.class") }}
  {{- $_ := set .Values.ingress.annotations "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" .Values.ingress.className}}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- if semverCompare ">=1.19-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
{{- else if semverCompare ">=1.14-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion -}}
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
{{- else -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
{{- end }}
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    {{- include "helm-db-example.labels" . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
  {{- if and .Values.ingress.className (semverCompare ">=1.18-0" .Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion) }}
  ingressClassName: {{ .Values.ingress.className }}
  {{- end }}
  {{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
        {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
        {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
    {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
  rules:
    {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
          {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ .path }}
            {{- if and .pathType (semverCompare ">=1.18-0" $.Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion) }}
            pathType: {{ .pathType }}
            {{- end }}
            backend:
              {{- if semverCompare ">=1.19-0" $.Capabilities.KubeVersion.GitVersion }}
              service:
                name: {{ $fullName }}
                port:
                  number: {{ $svcPort }}
              {{- else }}
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: {{ .Values.pgadminService.port }}
              {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

I am using minikube, trying minikube tunnel didn't work.

EDIT: In my pod's log i get this warning about my pgadmin containers:

> [1] [WARNING] Worker with pid 725 was terminated due to signal 9

Comment: What's actually going wrong?  Can you tell if the two containers start up?  I might structure this significantly differently: don't create either a PersistentVolume or a PersistentVolumeClaim directly; put the database as a single container in a StatefulSet; and run the admin tool as a single container in a separate Deployment.

Comment: The two containers are up and running. Have I to put them on different pods? They're already in different containers but in the same pod.

Comment: It's good practice.  In your update where the PGAdmin container fails, for example, you could update its configuration without restarting the underlying database.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.